# yargs (node module): command module files... parse the command, but without automatically executing the command's exports.handler code

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, typeorm, yargs

I'm using yargs with command modules, i.e. separate file for each command, with each command file defining `exports.command`, `exports.desc`, `exports.handler` for its own command.

For 60% of my commands, the way it works by default is fine.  But the other 40% I want to first connect to a database with TypeORM, which is async, and then only after the connection has been made, execute `exports.handler` wrapped inside a .then() so that it doesn't execute before the DB has connected.

The issue is that in my global entry file, as soon as all the global yargs options are defined, and I execute .argv for yargs to parse the command (which determines if it's a db or non-db command), it also executes `exports.handler` immediately, so I have no opportunity first connect to the database, and use .then to wrap the `exports.handler` command code (for the 40% of commands that need it).

I want to avoid having to add async code just for the db connection to every one of those 40% of command files.  And also avoid connecting to the db for all 100% of commands, as 60% of them don't need it.

I was about to make major changes and no longer use yargs' command modules... but there must be an easier way to do this?

Is there a way to tell yargs that I want to **parse** the command but not **execute** `exports.handler` yet?

If I can just figure that out, then I can simply segregate the commands that need to be wrapped inside .then() and those that don't.

Comment: Can you share the code that handles the logic whether to connect to DB or not?

Comment: I haven't actually even written the conditional code yet, that will be easy.  But I first need the value from `yargs.argv` to test on before I get to that. But as soon as I try to access `yargs.argv`, yargs executes my handler too.  Might be that I just need to rename `handler` to something else and no longer follow yargs' conventions.  But then I can't figure out how to get the module object to execute the exported code on.  Might be just that yargs' command modules are too limited to do this.

Comment: I use `yargs` but I am also not sure if what you asking is possible. as a hack you could peek into `process.argv` and check if it contains command that requires DB.